# Firebase sign out then switch Storyboard

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

For some reason the way I've implemented my sign out method isn't actually signing out the user. I think this is because I'm switching back to my login storyboard before Firebase finishes signing out. Here's what I have:

```
try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginStoryboard")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How do I make sure the user is signed out when the login view controller is presented?

Comment: Is the user being signed out after the controller is presented, or are they not being signed out at all?

Comment: Its actually signing out the user but then when I press the sign in button it doesn't go to the Gmail account picker thing, it just signs in with the account that was just logged out of automatically.

Comment: Got it. In that case you need to sign the user out of google as well. Right now you're only signing them out of Firebase. Try `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to move to the login view after you know the user has logged out, not before.

The signOut() function doesn't have a completion handler (hey firebase! add one) so you have to use another method to watch for state changes.

There are a couple of ways to do this but a simple one is to add a listener/observer for authentication state changes and proceed to the login controller once the state changes.

Something like this

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
    if let user = user {
        // user is signed in so don't do anything
    } else {
        //the user has now signed out so go to login view controller
        // and remove this listener
    }
}
```